# Construction of Primaries of WZWN CFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

Is it possible to construct primaries of $SU(2)_{k+1}$ by using primaries of lower levels?. 
E.g. If I have a primary of $SU(2)_2$, let's say $\Phi^{(1/2)}$, the field with spin $1/2$ and another field $\phi^{(1/2)}$ which is primary of $SU(2)_1$, also with spin 1/2, is there an algorithm to construct, using these two primaries, a primary of $SU(2)_3$.

Thanks